# Proving with stirlling approximation

Tags: algorithm, logarithm

How do you prove using Stirling's approximation?

```
           log(n!)=Θ(nlogn)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming (not even about algorithms), but about a mathematical proof.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming as defined in the help centre

Comment: @DSM I'm not opposed to migrating this question to the mathematics site. However, there have been other questions in the `algorithm` tag asking for big-O proofs, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274287/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043813/). Admittedly, this question involves slightly more advanced math.  Are we adamantly opposed to answering this question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you the broad outline of the proof. You'll have to fill in the details. From [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), Stirling's approximation states that for all positive integers *`n`*:

[image]

Using a little algebra to rearrange the terms, we get

[image]

So *`n!`* is bounded above and below by the function

[image]

Since we're interested in *`log(n!)`* we need to determine the behavior of *`log(f(n))`*  for large values of *`n`*. Doing some more algebra:

[image]

For large values of *n*, the first term is much larger than the rest, so

[image]

which completes the outline of the proof.